# How do I stream multiple logs to AWS CloudWatch from inside a Docker instance?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I am setting up Debian-based containers via AWS ECS on EC2 instances.  The container has a number of logs I want in separate CloudWatch streams.

The "expected" setup is to simply stream stdout to CloudWatch, but that only permits for one stream.

I tried to install the cloudwatch agent, but ran into myriad problems.  `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.` being the starting point.

Is this possible?

Comment: @jtlz2 see the answer i posted just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just streamed everything to stdout.  In my case it was Django/Gunicon:

```
echo "Starting gunicorn!"
gunicorn -c /etc/gunicorn/conf.py mydjangoapp.wsgi:application --bind unix:/tmp/app_proxy.sock --access-logfile - --error-logfile - --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm &

echo "Starting nginx..."
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```